# Linq query with where conditions (x && x) || (x & x)

Tags: c#, linq

```
char[] delimiter = new char[] {' '};

string[] names = name.Trim().Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

employees = (List<CMSUser>)employees.Where(
                    e => 
                       (e.FirstName.Contains(names[0]) && e.LastName.Contains(names[1])) ||
                       (e.LastName.Contains(name[0]) && e.FirstName.Contains(name[1]))
                     )
```

Above, I am trying to use Linq lambda to query employees List. I need to split the search term entered in input box for space character and use it to pull from employees list matching (FirstName && LastName) OR (LastName && FirstName) containing those two search words separated by space.

I don't know what I am doing wrong in query condition. It is returning all employees in list rather than giving those matching condition.

Comment: Variables with useful names are .. useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem happens in your second OR clause:

```
(e.LastName.Contains(name[0]) && e.FirstName.Contains(name[1])
```

It should be `names` not `name`, otherwise it gets the first and second characters respectively of the `name` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Casting an IEnumerable returned by `Where()` to a List should not work.  Instead you can use `ToList()`:

```
employees = employees.Where(
                    e => 
                       (e.FirstName.Contains(names[0]) && e.LastName.Contains(names[1])) ||
                       (e.LastName.Contains(names[0]) && e.FirstName.Contains(names[1]))
                     )
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: @RiskyMartis  yes I am doing that already in my code after Where then orderby and take and ToList. Thanks for noting that :)